# -webkit-flex-direction not showing on browser when using React

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox, webkit

I recently had to support a device that only worked with -webkit-flex in a React app. All css flex properties work fine when I add the **-webkit-** prefix, but the **-webkit-flex-direction** property does not appear in the browser. The css file loads fine, and all other properties appear and update correctly.

I tried with a non React app and the property works fine, so I know the problem lies with React. I created a minimal example here:
https://github.com/CarlesRojas/react-webkit-flex-direction-issue

The app was made using the create-react-app tool, and the only relevant files are:

```
src/App.js

src/App.css
```

Why is this one property not working? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no convincing information anywhere on the internet about why React does not recognize `-webkit-flex-direction` property but the following steps are a work-around solution for this problem according to your [minimal example code](https://github.com/CarlesRojas/react-webkit-flex-direction-issue):

1. Remove `import "./App.css";` file from `App.js`.
2. Move `App.css` file to the `public` folder.
3. Add `<link rel="stylesheet" href="App.css" />` to the `head` section of `index.html`

In this way, React cannot interfere with the contents of the external CSS file.

Comment: Ok! Thanks! Will try that!